# What is the difference between Text and String?

Tags: java

In going through the JavaFX tutorial I've run into the Text, and it's being used where I would have thought a String would be used. Is the only difference between

```
String foo = new String("bat");
```

and

```
Text bar = new Text("bat");
```

that bar cannot be edited, or are there other differences that I haven't been able to find in my research?

Comment: Well... as a starter, these are two completely different classes.

Comment: What the difference is? Basically everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of JavaFX, [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) is a class in the *javafx.scene.text* package. The Text class defines a node that displays a text. Paragraphs are separated by '\n' and the text is wrapped on paragraph boundaries. In other words, Text is a component of a scene graph.

[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), while also a class, is a fundamental data type in the Java language. String is in the *java.lang* package which is implicitly imported by the Java Compiler. The String class represents character strings. All string literals in Java, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class.

Similarities

- Both Text and String instances can contain "text" as a sequence of characters.

Differences

- String values are immutable in that you cannot change the value once you assign it but Text instances are mutable and can change by calling *setText()* method.

Methods that take a Text or String argument cannot be used interchangeably without converting to the appropriate class.

```
Text text = new Text("foo");
// convert Text to String
String s = text.getText(); // value = "foo"
// convert String to Text
text.setText(s); // or text = new Text(s) // value = "foo"
```

Comment: Note: `String` isn't a primitive.  It does have some special support which makes it more than just an ordinary class though, so meh.

Comment: Use String so often - taken for granted not a primitive. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 4):

A String is just a container for a character sequence. The Text class is a JavaFX class for displaying a String / Text on the display (and formatting like color, size, etc.). So it is basically a UI component.